# How Add PO Number Field for All Payment methods

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, payment-methods, knockoutjs

[image]

On checkout, there should be an input field for the PO number
Input needs to be available for all payment types and must be required.
Hide the default PO number in the Payment on Account payment method.